# In next.js app router how can I check for active Links that point to sections of a page

Tags: reactjs, path, navbar, next.js13

I have a navbar with some `Link` pointing to other pages and **other Links pointing to sections of pages**

I want to know which section is currently active. I tried the `usePathname` as suggested in  the docuemntation but this only shows the activa **page** not the section **within** the page:

```
import { usePathname} from 'next/navigation';

const NavBar = () => {
  const pathname = usePathname();  

  const isActive = (href) => {
    console.log(pathname)
    console.log(href)
    if (pathname.startsWith(href)) {
        return " text-orange-500 animation-active ";
    }
    return " text-black-500 hover:text-orange-500 ";
};
```

The logging above always show:

```
/
/#about
/
/#contact
```

so `pathname` is always the global page. in this case homepage `/`. but Even when I click on the sections, the `pathname` does not change event though the url itself changes.

**How can I get the active section within a page?**

Comment: use window.location.hash

Answer (score 0):

Use useRouter from next/router in Next.js for internal links with hash fragments to access the full path, including the hash, as usePathname from next/navigation only provides the current pathname without the hash.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const NavBar = () => {
  const { asPath } = useRouter();

  const isActive = (href) => {
    if (asPath.startsWith(href)) {
      return "text-orange-500 animation-active";
    }
    return "text-black-500 hover:text-orange-500";
  };
}
```

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/49465

Please also check the above link.

Thanks

Comment: This does not work. I said I am using the app router. So your answer is throwing this error: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

Answer (score 0):

I used React's `useState` and `useEffect` to track the currently active section. Here's a snippet of what I used:

```
const [activeSection, setActiveSection] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  const handleHashChange = () => {
    setActiveSection(window.location.hash);
  };

  window.addEventListener('hashchange', handleHashChange);
  handleHashChange();

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('hashchange', handleHashChange);
  };
}, []);
```

https://cnhdhy.csb.app/ (I've coded on codesandbox)

Comment: How do I add this listener to a next.js <Link> that is triggering my `isActive` function?

Comment: give a client component to track ..

Comment: wrap that client component anywhere in that page, 'use client' at the top is a client compoennt

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is similar to what is in this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/async-haze-7z2myv?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

Instead of using `inView` I used `IntersectionObserver` that looks for  the `entry.isIntersecting`. If Intersecting, set a visible state to the current component that is intersecting.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      ([entry]) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) setVisibleSection(entry.target.id);
      },
      {threshold: 0.1}
    );
    observer.observe(ref.current);
  }, []);
```